# How To Set Entry Point In C++ Program In VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I tried to change the entry point of my c++ program to the main function (because I want to try something)
I went to the advanced settings in the linker and I put in the Entry Point: main as you can see in the image below. [image: here].

And when I build the code with main as the entry point I get an error as you can see in the image above.
I tried to search for this error online and I didn't find anything useful.
And when I build the code without the entry point I got no errors.

Someone can help me please?

Comment: Care to share the error you get? What if you search for it online? As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I searched, and you can see the error in the image.

Comment: Please put the error message in the text, so the next one searching for that error will find it.

Comment: It seems you know how to solve the problem. What is your actual question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Remove the entry point to solve your problem.

Comment: I don't know how to solve the problem. I am trying to set the main function as the entry point of the program.

Comment: There are many things happening before a usual C++ enters the main function. If you want to use the main function as entry point you have to do the these things yourself. So the main question is what are you trying to achieve and why are changing the entry point.

Comment: I want to replace  mainCRTStartup because mainCRTStartup also do other things that I don't need. And I want to remove the VS signature and for that I need to put in the entry point the main function.

Comment: So your question is not "How to set entry point in VS" but how to link symbols after changing entry point: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7bbb584f-33a1-481c-864c-0184faa2a468/why-do-i-get-the-errors-below-when-i-use-the-entry-option-for-the-linker-in-a-c-project?forum=vcgeneral It seems that `mainCRTStartup` does something that is necessary for your program.

Comment: Please see the referrence page of VisualStudio regarding this topic. As far as I understood you have a wrong perception of what "Entry Point" is supposed to do. You can't just type in a random function name and expect your Program to start there

Comment: Thank You jabaa. You helped me to solve the problem. And alovaros I can  just type in a random function name and expect your Program to start there.